# Need to Run Script for Multiple Hosts in a CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to run the following code to check the connection status of multiple servers simultaneously from a CSV file that can be easily edited rather than an individual host each time.

I realise I can run the same script multiple times from within a bat, however for portability I would like the CSV functionality.

Bonus points if you can help me output the results to a log!

I effectively want to somehow combine the functionality of this script,

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ping-multiple-ip-addresses-3ac09a06

and the one provided below

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false, HelpMessage="HostName or IP Address")]
    [string]$HostName
)

[Console]::BackgroundColor = "Magenta"
Clear-Host
Write-Host $HostName
$LastState = $null
$LastTime = $null
do {
    $CurrentState = Test-Connection -ComputerName $HostName -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($CurrentState -ne $LastState) {
        $Now = Get-Date

        if ($LastTime -eq $null) {
            $Delta = ""
        } else {
            $Delta = ":  Duration was " + ($Now-$LastTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds "
        }

        if ($CurrentState -eq $true) {
            Write-Host "Responding " (Get-Date) $Delta -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host "Stopped " (Get-Date) $Delta -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    $LastState = $CurrentState
    $LastTime = $Now
    # Give the CPU a break
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} while (1 -eq 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if that script is doing what you want, then you really just need to configure it to accept csv input. Currently, it explicitly does not allow input from a pipe. So you'll want to change ValueFromPipeline=$false to ValueFromPipeline=$true. Then grab your csv and pipe the HostName to your script.

```
$hosts = Import-Csv .\HostTest.csv
foreach($endpoint in $hosts){.\testHost.ps1 $endpoint.Name}
```

For your second request, basic logging is really easy with powershell. Everywhere that you're currently writing output to the host shell, add or replace a line with:

```
Add-Content -Path path\to\log.file -Value "The same info you're writing to the host shell"
```

You can also use Set-Content -Path path\to\log$date.file to create new files for every process.